# Is this Out or Not Out in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is this Out or Not Out in cricket?

The batsman hits the ball with his bat, and the ball then hits the fielding helmet not being worn directly, it is then caught by the fielder without the ball ever hitting the ground.

Is this considered Out or Not Out?

Comment: Are we talking about the helmet on the field normally behind the wicket-keeper? The lack of punctuation makes the question a little unclear unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks. The Helmet could be behind the wicket-keeper or it could be anywhere kept on the field.

Comment: I have updated the question a little to hopefully make the question clearer. Feel free to edit it again if you think I have changed the subject of the question. Additionally, according to the Laws, a fielding helmet not in use can only be placed behind the wicket-keeper, and inline with both sets of stumps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, as there appears that there could be a conflict in the laws of the game depending on how they are enforced.

I personally believe this will be **Not Out**, as the ball striking the placed helmet will result in a Dead Ball - as per [Law 20.1.1.7](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/dead-ball) which states:

> **20.1.1** The ball becomes dead when
>
> [...]
>
> **20.1.1.7** there is contravention of Law 28.3 (Protective helmets belonging to the fielding side).

[Law 28.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-fielder) referring to the use of fielding helmets

> **28.3** Protective helmets belonging to the fielding side
>
> **28.3.1** Protective helmets, when not in use by fielders, may not be placed on the ground, above the surface except behind the wicket-keeper and in line with both sets of stumps.
>
> **28.3.2** If the ball while in play strikes a helmet, placed as described in 28.3.1
>
> **28.3.2.1** the ball shall become dead

However, under [Law 33.1 - Caught](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/caught), it states that a catch taken after hitting an obstruction that is not the boundary (as considered by the umpires) is considered a fair catch:

> **33.2.2** Furthermore, a catch will be fair if any of the following conditions applies:
>
> [...]
>
> **33.2.2.5** **the ball is caught off an obstruction within the boundary that is not designated a boundary by the umpires.**

in which case you could make the case that the decision should be **Out**.

I guess the argument here is whether the ball is considered Dead *immediately* after striking the helmet, in which the batter will be Not Out, or if play is allowed to continue and a fair catch is made, then it would be Out. However there does not appear to be a law that states this explicitly.

Comment: I think Law 20 makes the reasonable assumption that the effect of Dead ball is immediate and instantaneous. Otherwise one could argue for all manner of silly things based on the argument that play continues even though it has stopped, which would simply not *"be cricket"*. It would bring into question the entire point of Dead ball.

Answer (score -1):

So it's out out.  As per [law 28.3.2.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-fielder) the ball becomes dead instantly.

No wickets can be taken after the ball is dead.

Comment: Please add a reference to your answr.